# How to wait for reply in an async function before executing .then

Tags: node.js, async-await, telegraf

I'm trying to wait for the user to select an age before the .then triggers but I am unable to do so. Would it be better to just split the function up instead of using .then?

Thank you

```
async function x() {
        await ctx
            .reply(
                'Select your age',
                Markup.keyboard([
                    ['10'],
                    ['11'],
                    ['12'],
                ])
                    .oneTime()
                    .resize()
            )
            .then(() => {
                admin
                    .database()
                    .ref('users/' + ctx.message.chat.id)
                    .set({
                        username: ctx.message.from.first_name,
                        rank: ctx.message.text,
                    });
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for user replay with async.

You need to create a different reaction when the user sends a request to you.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of an async function only becomes apparent when you combine it with the await keyword. await only works inside async functions within regular JavaScript code, however it can be used on it's own with JavaScript modules.

await can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the resulting value.

You can use await when calling any function that returns a Promise, including web API functions.

```
async function x() {
        let results = await ctx.reply('Select your age',Markup.keyboard([
                    ['10'],
                    ['11'],
                    ['12'],
                ])
                    .oneTime()
                    .resize()
            );
           if (results) {
              admin
                    .database()
                    .ref('users/' + ctx.message.chat.id)
                    .set({
                        username: ctx.message.from.first_name,
                        rank: ctx.message.text,
                    });

           }
           else {
             // log error or throw error
             }
    }
```

You can check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to get more details how to use promises with async/await